# Set Compose Key on Centos 7 Desktop

Tags: centos

How can I set the Compose Key on a CentOS 7 desktop environment? All of the documentation I've found for other systems says:

- System > Preferences > Keyboard
- Select the Layouts tab
- Click on Layout Options...
- Expand Position of Compose key
- Select the key(s) you want to act as the compose key
- Close

But on my CentOS 7 desktop, there isn't a layouts tab. There is an "Input Sources" screen, but it only lets you select language and formats from pre-defined layouts; there's not a Layout Options button as described in these steps.

Is there some way I can set it with gconf or a config file somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally like to use the compose key too.

- Select Applications>System Tools Select
- Select Keyboard
- Click on the shortcuts tab
- Click on "Typing" option
- There should be a "Compose Key" option, the default is for it to be disabled. Then select it and change it to have the key you like to use, for example "Right Win".